# Grouping date ranges in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, pandas-groupby

Was trying to get output with date range(weekly). i am able to group the date and sum the values but how to get the output as per the below image. tried pd.grouping with frequency, resample with  no luck any other methods can help?

looking for the desired output as per the image

[image: output highlighted]

Answer (score 0):

`resample` works on time series data. If you want to resample a DataFrame, it should either have a DateTime index or you need to pass `on` parameter to `resample`.

This should work
`df.resample('W', on='Date').sum()`

`W` is the weekly frequency, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects).

Another option you might explor is [cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), but IMO resample will be better for what you need.